# Name of the Gtk+ widget used in the gnome tweak tool as side menu

Tags: widget, gtk, gtk3, glade, gtkmm

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool]

Name of that Gtk widget on the side which has options: "Apperance", "Desktop" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget you are referring to seems to be a `GtkStackSidebar`. It's documentation can be found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStackSidebar.html).

If you are trying to id widgets in the future check the [GTK3 Widget Gallery](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch03.html) it contains a collection of the most common widget including screenshots so that should help.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can I find it in Glade ?

Comment: A way to ID widgets directly is to enable the GTK+ Inspector and use that. StackSidebar was only added in recent versions of Glade and you can find it under Controls. You're supposed to use it with a Stack (under Containers).